Cannot export NDVI map to google drive on Google Earth Engine
I am trying to export an image of NDVI before a wildfire to my Google Drive but it keeps failing and I am unsure of what the issue is.
the variable burntsite is a polygon I drew.
 var prefire = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2000-07-30', '2007-07-30')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5)
    .filterBounds(burntsite);

var addndvi = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var prefireNDVI = prefire.map(addndvi);

var ndvivis = {min: -0.1, max: 1, palette: 
  ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', 
   '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', 
   '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01','011301']
  };

var clippedprefireNDVI = prefireNDVI.map(function(image){
  return image.clip(burntsite).select('NDVI');
});

// Add the clipped NDVI images to the map
Map.addLayer(clippedprefireNDVI, ndvivis, 'Prefire NDVI 2000-2007');

//trying to export
Export.image.toDrive({image:clippedpostfireNDVI, region:burntsite, description:'ndvi', folder:'IB', scale:30});


and what is the error you face (because "it doesn't work" is not helping someone that does not see your screen) ?

It seems like there’s a small mistake in your code. You’re trying to export clippedpostfireNDVI, but this variable is not defined in your code. You probably meant to export clippedprefireNDVI.
